Delete swift object after leaving view
I have a workout application using SwiftData where the user can start a new workout. When clicking the start button, the user is redirected to a new view (CurrentWorkoutView) in which a workout object is instantiated. The user could then save or cancel the workout.
I'm facing 2 problems:

The workout is being instantiated as soon as the app is launched
The workout is not being "dropped" after the user saves/cancels the workout

This is a simplified version of the code:
// HomeView.swift

...

NavigationLink("Start Workout") {
    CurrentWorkoutView()
}

...

// CurrentWorkoutView.swift

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    
@Bindable var workout: Workout = Workout()

var body: some View {

    ...

    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
            Button("Save") {
                workout.end = Date.now
                context.insert(workout)
                dismiss()
            }
        }
            
        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
            Button("Cancel") {
                context.delete(workout)
                try! context.save()
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried to set workout as nullable but, because it's bindable, I can't. It has to be bindable to allow for title, description, etc editing.

You should not use @Bindable when it’s the view that owns the object, use State instead here. And with @State we can make the property optional as well
@State private var workout: Workout?

Create it in onAppear
.onAppear {
    workout = Workout()
}

And since the object has not been inserted into the ModelContext you don’t need to delete it either, just set it to nil in the Cancel button action

Had to do a workaround to allow the textfield bindings to work with an optional field but this did fix my issue. Thanks!!
